# How can I refactor this if elif statements?

Tags: python

There is list of grades - [a,b,c,d,e,f]

```
grade = int(input())
if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
    print('a')
elif grade >=70 and grade <= 80:
    print('b')
elif grade >=60 and grade <= 70:
    print('c')
elif grade >= 50 and grade <= 60:
    print('d')
elif grade < 50:
    print('e')
```

How can I rewrite this elegantly in 2-3 lines of code?

Like, there is dictionary with key grades 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and it prints depending on the grade?

Comment: What happens at 85? And you should check the output for 70.

Comment: What happens at 70?

Comment: @ToniSredanović 70 in covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `zip` grades and thresholds:

```
grades = "edcba"
limits = [50, 60, 70, 80, 100]  # I think that 80-90 gap is not intentional
grade = int(input())
for limit, letter in zip(limits, grades):
    if grade <= limit:
        print(letter)
        break
else:
    print("Not found!")
```

Comment: or just directly defines a list of `(grade, limit)` pairs... but that's obviously the best answer so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
grades =  {'a': range(90,100), 'b': range(80,90),'c': range(70,80), 'd': range(60,70), 'e': range(50,60)}

grade = int(input())

for key,value in grades.items():
    if grade in value:
        print (key)
```

or just use list comprehension:

```
grades =  {'a': range(90,100), 'b': range(80,90),'c': range(70,80), 'd':range(60,70), 'e': range(50,60)}

grade = int(input())

print ([key for key,value in grades.items() if grade in value][0])
```

Comment: In addition to being almost a _one_-liner, this approach has the added benefit of constant lookup time each time it needs to be used +1.

Comment: That second suggestion is bonkers: why re-write the concept of a math look-up?  The first idea is good, though.

Comment: It also has the inconvenient of building useless lists (py2) or `range` (py3) objects and doing a totally inefficient sequential lookup. This would not pass a code review or merge request here, definitly.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you elaborate on inefficient sequential lookup time?

Comment: @Rahul in python2, `range()` returns a `list` so the the containment test is a sequential lookup which is O(n). In Python3, constant time containment on `range` objects has only been implemented in 3.2. If the question had been tagged "python3" I would just have mentionned this last point, but since it's tagged as "python" in general the answers should take Python2 into account too or explicitely mention that they are p3 only - which is not the case here. And yes, there are still quite a lot of python2 code around so it's not purely academic.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could easily get rid of one half of the range checks, by rephrasing as follows:

```
grade = int(input())
if grade < 50:
    print('e')
elif grade <= 60:
    print('d')
elif grade <= 70:
    print('c')
elif grade <= 80:
    print('b')
elif grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
    print('a')
else
    print('unknown')
```

I am not sure if your `90 <= grade <= 100` range is accurate, or if you intended for it to be adjacent to the previous lower range.  In any case, it does not change my suggested refactor much.